# Is there any clue in Hinduism religion that depicts "Tree has life"?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, krishna, puranas

Is there any clue in Hinduism religion that depicts Tree has life? If anyone has answer please answer it.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is pointing towards life i.e. "jiva". The other duplicate question was about the "Soul" or "Atma". Although we in Hinduism believe both are inseprable , but others may not . Or will be having different angle/view. So I think both questions are different , and should be adressed / answered sepratly.

Comment: Correctly said.I don't know how to remove the duplicate tag. @SwiftPushkar